# New content forces to top of site - having some basic layout issues -

Tags: html, css, layout

I've done this a few times on websites, but this is one of the first times I've tried making a website with a width of 100%. I'm really enjoying the way the site looks compared to being in a wrapper with a set width, but now I'm having all kinds of basic layout issues.

I'm trying to make a layout that has a slide show at the top that is 100% width. Within the slideshow I have the website logo and nav bar positioned above the slider. I pulled this off by making the slideshow absolute and the nav bar and logo relative.  So far no problem. Now I want to start adding content below the slider. When I try to add the next div which is going to be the `<div id="menu">`, the div launches to the top of the screen behind the slideshow. I've noticed this has to do with the slideshow being absolute positioned because when I remove it, the `<div id="menu">` goes back to the bottom of the screen.

How do I add more content below the slider with a background-image all inside the `<div id="menu">`?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/kDR6e/)

Comment: Your fiddle is a bit of a mess (probably because of all the missing images). To make things more visual, you could add a specific background color to each element, that always helps me to have a better look on what goes where when I'm writing a page.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what your issue is. Are you asking how to add a background image to the div? Why do you need the slideshow to be absolutely positioned? It is hard to tell how removing the absolute positioning messes things up based on your JS Fiddle.